# Client Side Pagination via JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have 3 files

1. index.php
2. js file
3. a.php

i am sending ajax query to a.php from index.php and ajax code is written in js file means
Request => `index.php->js->a.php`

Ajax Code is given below :

```
$.ajax({    
        type    : "POST",
        cache   : true,
        dataType: "json",
        url     : "a.php",
        //async:false,
        data    : {
                    proid:id
                  },                
        success: function(data) {

            //console.log(data);
            var a = data.length;




        }
    });
```

a.php return dynamic array of Divs. It may 3, 4, 5,...so...on. This result is come in ajax success function.
I want to show Div on index.php one at a time. and i want also a next and previous button to show next div or previous div and how to use json return Data use in index.php.?? Is there any functionality to use this array directly goes to index.php and there we iterate it as per our requirement. Please help me...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/) if I were you. It has a very easy-to-implement [tabbed navigation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) plugin that you can fill with a few simple DOM manipulations (`$(foo).html(bar)`, `$(foo).append(bar)`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have this markup in your index.php to load the json data coming by your ajax request.

```
<div id='divCarousal'></div>
<input type='button' id='prev' value='Prev' />
<input type='button' id='next' value='Next' />​
```

Finally using the following ajax code you can populate your carousal div.

```
$.ajax({    
        type    : "POST",
        cache   : true,
        dataType: "json",
        url     : "a.php",
        success: function(data) {
            //Below is the dummy data 
            var data = [ 
                {"div": '<div>1</div>'}, 
                {"div": '<div>2</div>'}, 
                {"div": '<div>3</div>'}
            ];
            $.each (data, function () {
                $('#divCarousal').append(this.div);
            });

            $('#divCarousal').children('div:not(:first)').hide();

            $('#next').click(function () {
                $('div#divCarousal > div:visible').hide().next().show();
                if ($('div#divCarousal > div:visible').next().length == 0) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $('#prev').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            });

             $('#prev').click(function () {
                $('div#divCarousal > div:visible').hide().prev().show();
                if ($('div#divCarousal > div:visible').prev().length == 0) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                }  else {
                    $('#next').attr('disabled', false);
                }  
            });
        }
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ufDtm/